# Replace root document with array using MongoDB 4

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My aggregation pipeline is a document with a single field `result` that contains an array, like this:

```
[
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "meteoEventType": "RAIN",
        "meteoEventLabel": "PRECIPITAZIONE",
        "meteoEventLevel": "LOW",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Forte pioviggine"
      },
      {
        "meteoEventType": "HAIL",
        "meteoEventLabel": "GRANDINE",
        "meteoEventLevel": "MEDIUM",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Probabilità moderata"
      },
      {
        "meteoEventType": "INUNDATION",
        "meteoEventLabel": "ALLAGAMENTI",
        "meteoEventLevel": "LOW",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Probabilità molto bassa"
      },
      {
        "meteoEventType": "WIND",
        "meteoEventLabel": "VENTO",
        "meteoEventLevel": "LOW",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Calma"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I need to achieve is something like this, without the `result` field:

```
[
      {
        "meteoEventType": "RAIN",
        "meteoEventLabel": "PRECIPITAZIONE",
        "meteoEventLevel": "LOW",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Forte pioviggine"
      },
      {
        "meteoEventType": "HAIL",
        "meteoEventLabel": "GRANDINE",
        "meteoEventLevel": "MEDIUM",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Probabilità moderata"
      },
      {
        "meteoEventType": "INUNDATION",
        "meteoEventLabel": "ALLAGAMENTI",
        "meteoEventLevel": "LOW",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Probabilità molto bassa"
      },
      {
        "meteoEventType": "WIND",
        "meteoEventLabel": "VENTO",
        "meteoEventLevel": "LOW",
        "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Calma"
      }
    ]
```

Considering that I am using MongoDB 4, how can I get rid of the `result` field?

The `$replaceWith` stage can't work because `result` is not a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `$unwind` stage to deconstruct the `result` array before the `$replaceWith` stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$result"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$result"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qJdDBgzK-Mu)